# CoreWCF service holding a session over NetTcp

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, corewcf

In order to port a couple of WCF services to .NET6 I tried to create a setup with multiple WCF services provided by one server.

One of the services requried a session which brought me to adding a NetTcp endpoint.

Unfortunatly adding the NetTcp setup seems to break everything else on the server.
E.g. another service that was so far available via a BasicHttp endpoint is not available afterwards or I can't find a way to access the metadata endpoint for generating clients.

I created a basic sample setup for this use case at Github
[CoreWCF NetTcp session sample](https://github.com/MontyGvMC/CoreWCF-NetTcpSession-Sample)

and tried my luck at the CoreWCF issues page
[WCF service with session over NetTcp](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF/issues/1124)

So my concrete question is how to integrate the NetTcp setup into a server and still have the other setup working (metadata endpoint, basic http service)?

Is this even possible?

---

Forgive not posting the code here in the question since it is too much code for a single post. That's why I created the public git repo.